# unable to locate visual studio installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When I trying to open visual studio installer in visual studio 2017 an error message is displayed: **can't locate visual studio installer**. It might be because I deleted it by mistake. I tried to look for the download of visual studio installer  and did not find it. I must delete complitly visual studio 2017 from my drive as fast as it possible.

Comment: Is this a question... What is your question? You already said it might be because you deleted something by mistake. So just reinstall vs 2017.

Comment: I HAVE Visual Studio Installer...However, VS cannot seem to find it??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to control panel>>Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features>>right click on visual studio>>select change.
your installer window will appear on the screen.

Answer (score 5):

Try below link

https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15#

- Download installer from above link and then run installer.
- It will automatically display your installed vs 2017 components
- From there you can install/uninstall vs 2017

Answer (score 2):

Run the installer again. You don't have to uninstall first. I had the same problem when updating to v15.2 today.